# Prevent Overflow content from taking up space

Tags: html, css

I have a container div `listings_container` that contains a variable number of divs `listing`, each clearing the div before it. The container div `listings_container` has the CSS property `overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: auto;` and a fixed `width` and a `max-height` defined.

**Problem:** How do I prevent the overflowed divs from taking up space? Say `listings_container` has a height of 30px and `listing` has a height of 10 px. If we have 4 or more `listing` inside `listings_container`, we the 4th `listing` div onwards will be hidden and a vertical scrollbar appears for `listing_cotainer`. The space taken up by the overflowing `listing` div can cause `listings_container`to clear another floated div, which is what I want to avoid.

Any help really appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: How about put the html code here for the others easier to understand. I think you can try `#lisings_container{ overflow : hidden }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overflow content will always go beyond the boundary of the control if you leave it at auto which produces a pretty unusable effect. If you set the size of a div you typically wouldn't want to use auto unless you know the content won't overflow.

Your options are either to hide or to scroll to keep the size fixed. Personally I use scroll containers for this which is basically using overflow-y: scroll; and then use a fixed height.